# Why Is My API Not Returning Nested Object (.NET 6 Entity Framework and SQL DB)

Tags: c#, sql, .net, api, entity-framework

I have created an API, using EF and database first approach via scaffolding.

I have the following in my context file

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Request>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Request", "rmr");

            entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.RaisedBy).HasMaxLength(256);

            entity.Property(e => e.WorklistName).HasMaxLength(32);

        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<RequestLine>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.RequestId, e.LineNumber })
                .HasName("PK_RMR_REQUESTLINE");

            entity.ToTable("RequestLine", "rmr");

            entity.Property(e => e.Batch).HasMaxLength(32);

            entity.Property(e => e.CancelBy).HasMaxLength(256);

            entity.Property(e => e.CancelDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.CostCentre).HasMaxLength(32);

            entity.Property(e => e.Destination).HasMaxLength(32);

            entity.Property(e => e.FirstDeliveryDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.ProcessOrder).HasMaxLength(32);

            entity.Property(e => e.Sku)
                .HasMaxLength(32)
                .HasColumnName("SKU");

            entity.Property(e => e.SubmittedDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Request)
                .WithMany(p => p.RequestLines)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.RequestId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_RMR_REQUESTLINE_REQUEST");
        });
```

and then the following in my models

Request:

```
public partial class Request
{
    public Request()
    {
        RequestLines = new HashSet<RequestLine>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string RaisedBy { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string? WorklistName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RequestLine> RequestLines { get; set; }
}
```

Request Line:

```
public partial class RequestLine
{

    public long RequestId { get; set; }
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Batch { get; set; } = null!;
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string? CostCentre { get; set; }
    public string? ProcessOrder { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateTime FirstDeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SubmittedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CancelDate { get; set; }
    public string? CancelBy { get; set; }
}
```

My Request controller looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Request>>> GetRequests()
{
  if (_context.Requests == null)
  {
      return NotFound();
  }
    return await _context.Requests.ToListAsync();
}
```

In Swagger, it is displayed correctly in the example, based on the model:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "raisedBy": "string",
    "createdOn": "2022-06-15T17:32:27.129Z",
    "worklistName": "string",
    "requestLines": [
      {
        "requestId": 0,
        "lineNumber": 0,
        "sku": "string",
        "batch": "string",
        "quantity": 0,
        "costCentre": "string",
        "processOrder": "string",
        "destination": "string",
        "firstDeliveryDate": "2022-06-15T17:32:27.129Z",
        "submittedDate": "2022-06-15T17:32:27.129Z",
        "cancelDate": "2022-06-15T17:32:27.129Z",
        "cancelBy": "string",
        "request": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But when running the GET, what I am actually seeing is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "raisedBy": "GEORGE",
    "createdOn": "2022-06-13T13:14:31.813",
    "worklistName": "WORKLIST1",
    "requestLines": []
  },
  {
    "id": 10008,
    "raisedBy": "FFFFFF",
    "createdOn": "2022-06-15T16:34:18.297",
    "worklistName": "WORKLIST1",
    "requestLines": []
  }
]
```

The requestLines lists are showing empty, but there is data present in my DB for these.

Apologies for the length of the question. If further information is needed please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't use `Include`, but if you do that you have to prevent reference loops in the JSON serializer.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for your response - That worked for me and I got around the reference loop issue by using DTOs instead.

I have another quick question if you're able to help please? - Where would I use the Include for Get by a specific ID? 

So my Get all method looks like: 

var requests = await _context.Requests.Include(x => x.RequestLines).ToListAsync();
var requestDtos = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<RequestGetDTO>>(requests);

But I can't use an Include for my Get by ID as it seems to throw an error

var request = await _context.Requests.FindAsync(id);

Comment: `FindAsync` doesn't have `Include`, use `SingleOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
return await _context.Requests.Include(x => x.RequestLines).ToListAsync();
```